# merge two persistent store icloud store and non icloud store

Tags: ios, icloud

I have an iOS app where half the users want to use iCloud to synch some data between devices, and the other half don't.  For this reason I put the Core Data's (iCloud enabled) sqlite file in the application document directories. The iCloud syncs work nicely when they are signed in to iCloud.  However, if a user is not signed in.But if user not sign in then the sync data not merge with icloud data. The transactions logs obviously don't get created because the user is not using iCloud. However, the user may start using iCloud at a later date.   For this reason I think I need to create a second "fallback" persistent store that gets used when not signed into iCloud. If the user signs in later I would merge the fallback store with the iCloud enabled store.   My question is, does anybody know how I could easily merge the fallback (non iCloud) store with the iCloud enabled store. Secondly, does anybody have a better design as far as persistent store locations go?  Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this link for a sample app that supports use of a local or iCloud store and handles migration to and from iCloud.
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: Thanx for the link i will check it out and give feedback about that .

Comment: hey duncan thax for the help ..... can you just tell me how to upload and retrieve sqlite file in icloud and replace the sqlite file with current local sqlite file

Comment: Would love to but I don't really understand what you are trying to do that isn't already done in the sample application.  Have you watched the videos?  Have you installed the sample app and run it?  have you changed the various iCloud settings to see how files are moved to and from iCloud and synced between devices ?  If so then what exactly do you want your app to do that is different from what the sample app does?

Comment: i have seen that videos it is nice and very helpfull but now i just want to upload my sqlite database on cloud for backup .... and when the user press restore it fetch the sqlite database from icloud and replace the local sqlite file withe icloud version . thanx if you can help me out to do that.

Comment: Apple will probably reject your app for not following their storage guidelines.  I would recommend you place your files in the local /Documents directory and then get the user to turn on iCloud Backups.  That way all the documents will be backed up.  Get your app to make backup copies using the same method the sample app uses and write some code to display the list of files to let the user select the backup file to restore.  iCloud Document and Data is not meant for backups.

Comment: my sqlite coredata is stored in document directories i want to copy it into icloud for backup is it possible? and retrive it when restore it and replace it with sqlite file store in document directories

Comment: Copying documents into the apps iCloud ubiquity container results in the file being replicated to all devices running the app, it is not intended for backups. You can't 'copy' a file to iCloud nor can you 'download' a file from iCloud. You should do some more research to understand how iCloud works and what it is intended for. Dropbox might be a better option for you.

Comment: The sample application is very usefull thanx duncan